# Avoid the overhead of reading the V-Table upon every function-call, when there is only one class in the class-hierarchy

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions, vtable

I have a class which may or may not be extended (inherited) by other parties.

So I declare every function which is "plausibly-inheritable" as `virtual`.

On my current application, however, this class is never inherited.

So it seems wasteful to do so, due to the overhead of reading the V-Table upon every function-call.

I've been trying to think of a way to optimize it when there is **only one** V-Table in the class hierarchy.

But it seems impossible, since the compiler cannot infer this vital piece of information.

So the only solution that comes to mind is with the preprocessor, but I doubt that there is one.

I'm pretty sure I'm not the first one to encounter this problem, so any suggestions will be appreciated...

**UPDATE:**

Perhaps I should just leave the header file without any `virtual`, and let other users add it if needed.

But it doesn't sound like the right way...

Comment: Have you *measured* that this is actually a problem? If you often call via the (same) vtable, it should be in cache and rather quick to read. What cannot happen w/o extensive static analysis however, is *inlining* the function call.

Comment: I think you can find further information if you search for the term *devirtualization*.

Comment: You could derive from this class and make the derived class final; then use this derived class in your code. This should *allow* the compiler to make some optimizations when it *knows* that the object on which a member function is called is of the derived type.

Comment: and then check the generated code to see if the compiler is *actually* doing the optimization.

Comment: @dyp: What does "make the derived class final" mean?

Comment: @barakmanos: it means search for `c++ final class`.

Comment: @barakmanos Better, search for *c++11 final class*. It's a C++11 feature. It forbids deriving from a class. This implies that any virtual functions won't be overriden, and their final overriders are known (at compile-time!) in an expression which has the type of this final class.

Comment: @dyp: Thanks, I was pretty sure for a second that you were mixing up with Java or something... So am I to assume that it will not have backward-compatibility with older C++ versions?

Comment: Since it's a new C++11 feature, C++03/98 does not support `final`. However, it is implemented already in gcc4.7, VS2010 and clang++3.0 respectively.

Answer (score 1):

If you verified, that this is a bottleneck, then it might worth to do this small workaround:

```
#define omg_virtual
```

And later when you add more classes:

```
#define omg_virtual virtual
```

Or simply do a search-replace on the code base.

Comment: Oh My God virtual? Thanks, this simple solution evaded me for some reason... Though users will have to define it either directly in the header file (which means, changing the header file), or before every `include` of that header file (which seems "clumsy"), or in the project settings.

Comment: it should be in the header, as it's part of the API.

Comment: So that means users will have to change the header then, right?

Comment: what users? can people derive from your class? the header is like a contract. in that case I wouldn't do anything or explicitly tell how to configure it to gain speed (and make virtual the default)

Comment: Yes, that's the purpose of the question to begin with: "I have a class which may or may not be extended (inherited) by other parties" (the first line in the question).

Comment: sry, missed that part. see the previous comment. I assume you don't need binary compatiblity (.so/dll)

Answer (score 0):

You should not make every method virtual. It should be a real design decision, and the tradeoff is a small performance hit against flexibility.

For your use case, it is very probable the compiler can infer your call to virtual method doesn't need a lookup to the vtable and will discard it by iself.

Comment: Thanks, but how can the compiler infer that? It compiles each source file independently, without collecting any "global information".